# Does anyone have any tips on how to use Worldslayer in a Knight deck in Magic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I know that anyone that uses [Worldslayer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Worldslayer) tends to put it in decks with high res abilities such as [Gravedigger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gravedigger) and [Raise Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Raise%20Dead) where you can easily retrieve your creatures from the graveyard making it harder for your opponent to bounce back from the effects of Worldslayer, or in low mana cycle decks using cards with 3 or 4 converted mana at the most making it easy to swarm the field back up. But I obviously wouldn't be asking this if I had access to a well built deck with these characteristics so I decided that a Knight deck would be putting it to good use, so with this information does anyone have any tips on how to put a halfway decent Knight deck together while being able to use Worldslayer?

I saw a comment from someone that asked what I meant by "high res abilities" and "low mana cycle", well more or less res abilities are just cards like Gravekeeper and Marshal's Anthem, and I just say low mana cycle because I'm used to talking about videogames with my friends and for the most part if I said curve it would confuse them because none of them really play MTG and now that I think about it just about my whole grade doesn't.

Comment: What format are you playing?

Comment: Do you want to build a knights deck with Worldslayer in it or a Worldslayer deck with knights in it? What aspect do you want to focus on?

Comment: @Allure Worldslayer's only legal in Modern, Legacy, Vintage, and Commander. If the OP is trying to build a Knight deck themed around it, and they're not informed enough on MtG lingo to use the proper terms for things like mana curve, I'm guessing probably not Legacy or Vintage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Knight Exemplar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20Exemplar) comes to mind immediately; it lets your other Knights survive Worldslayer's effect.

[Fervent Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fervent%20Champion) or [Balan, Wandering Knight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Balan%2C%20Wandering%20Knight) can help with getting it attached.

[Armored Skyhunter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Armored%20Skyhunter) can bypass both the mana cost and the equip cost of Worldslayer.

[Acclaimed Contender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Acclaimed%20Contender) can pick up Worldslayer or your other Knights.

Answer (score 3):

Worldslayer is a bad card. It costs a staggering 5 mana to cast, 5 mana to equip, doesn't add any stats to the equipped creature, and you need to connect to get the effect. Compare the much more powerful equipment Swords of X and Y, e.g. [Sword of Fire and Ice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sword%20of%20Fire%20and%20Ice) or [Sword of Feast and Famine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sword%20of%20Feast%20and%20Famine), which have none of these problems. The silver lining is that if you do connect and your deck is able to take advantage of the effect, you probably win since you also blow up all lands and opponents cannot cast spells anymore, but the effort required to connect is tremendous.

If you're going to play with this card anyway ...

- Use something that searches up the card - [Stoneforge Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stoneforge%20Mystic) is the standard for this. [Steelshaper's Gift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Steelshaper%27s%20Gift) can do it too, but Mystic can also put it into play next turn for discounted price.
- Use something that reduces the equip cost - [Sigarda's Aid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sigarda%27s%20Aid), [Puresteel Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Puresteel%20Paladin).
- Use something evasive to connect with it. A creature that cannot be blocked is ideal, but something that flies might also suffice.
- Use something to break the symmetry. Indestructible permanents (including indestructible lands) are ideal, or at least cards that do something when they die.

Some ideas off the top of my head:

- [Flagstones of Trokair](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flagstones%20of%20Trokair)
- [Avacyn, Angel of Hope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avacyn%2C%20Angel%20of%20Hope)
- [Darksteel Citadel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Citadel) (counts as an artifact to trigger metalcraft if you're using Puresteel Paladin)

Don't expect to be competitive though - it'd strictly be for casual play.

Comment: "Worldslayer is a bad card." It is, but it might be *okay* in Commander, since cards with a higher CMC are typically more viable in Commander, and an board wipes are more valuable when you hit multiple players.